# How to disable some moving averages based on bool input in pine scripts?

Tags: pine-script, trading

I have six moving averages that I use. But I want to disable 7 and 20 when using the daily chart and disable 200 and 300 when using the weekly chart. Hence, I am taking bool input "Daily MA" and "Weekly MA".

I am stuck here and not sure what to do from here. Do I use the if statement?

```
// Moving Averages
exponential = input(false, title="Exponential MA")
dailyma = input(true, title="Daily MA")
weeklyma = input(true, title="Weekly MA")

ma7 = exponential ? ema(src, 7) : sma(src, 7)
ma20 = exponential ? ema(src, 20) : sma(src, 20)
ma50 = exponential ? ema(src, 50) : sma(src, 50)
ma128 = exponential ? ema(src, 128) : sma(src, 128)
ma200 = exponential ? ema(src, 200) : sma(src, 200)
ma300 = exponential ? ema(src, 300) : sma(src, 300)

plot( ma7, color=orange, style=line, title="MA7", linewidth=1)
plot( ma20, color=black, style=line, title="MA20", linewidth=1)
plot( ma50, color=fuchsia, style=line, title="MA50", linewidth=1)
plot( ma128, color=purple, style=line, title="MA128", linewidth=1)
plot( ma200, color=black, style=line, title="MA200", linewidth=1)
plot( ma300, color=green, style=line, title="MA300", linewidth=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide it using conditional colors.

```
plot( ma7, color=timeframe.isdaily ? na : orange, style=line, title="MA7", linewidth=1)
plot( ma20, color=timeframe.isdaily ? na : black, style=line, title="MA20", linewidth=1)

plot( ma200, color=timeframe.isweekly ? na : black, style=line, title="MA200", linewidth=1)
plot( ma300, color=timeframe.isweekly ? na : green, style=line, title="MA300", linewidth=1)
```

**Edit:** with bool input added to the condition

```
plot( ma7, color=timeframe.isdaily and dailyma ? na : orange, style=line, title="MA7", linewidth=1)
plot( ma20, color=timeframe.isdaily and dailyma ? na : black, style=line, title="MA20", linewidth=1)

plot( ma200, color=timeframe.isweekly and weeklyma ? na : black, style=line, title="MA200", linewidth=1)
plot( ma300, color=timeframe.isweekly and weeklyma ? na : green, style=line, title="MA300", linewidth=1)
```

**Edit:** version=4

```
plot( ma7, color=timeframe.isdaily and dailyma ? na : color.orange, title="MA7")
plot( ma20, color=timeframe.isdaily and dailyma ? na : color.black, title="MA20")

plot( ma200, color=timeframe.isweekly and weeklyma ? na : color.black, title="MA200")
plot( ma300, color=timeframe.isweekly and weeklyma ? na : color.green, title="MA300")
```

Comment: It returned ```Undeclared identifier `timeframe.isdaily` ``` I got it solved by writing ```plot( ma7, color=dailyma==true ? na : orange, style=line, title="MA7", linewidth=1)``` ...

Comment: It's probably because you aren't using version=4.

Comment: Plot style line can't be used on V4.

Comment: Edited my answer, added code for version=4.

Comment: If you want to keep style, you can use `style=plot.style_line`. By default it's already set to that.